# Issues trying to insert string to SQL Server

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a string to a SQL DB starting with `0x` but it keeps failing on the insert. The characters that come after `0x` are random characters that range from A-Z, a-z and 0-9 with no set length. I tried to get around it by adding a letter in front of the string and update it afterwards but it does not work. I am using

SQL statement I am trying to mimic

```
insert into [TestDB].[dbo].[S3_Files] ([Key],[IsLatest],[LastModified],[MarkedForDelete],[VersionID]) values ('pmtg-dox/CCM/Trades/Buy/Seller_Provided_-_Raw_Data/C''Ds_v2/NID3153422.pdf','1','2015-10-11','Yes', '0xih91kjhdaoi23ojsdpf')
```

Python Code

```
import pymssql as mssql
...
cursor.execute("insert into [TestDB].[dbo].[S3_Files] ([Key],[IsLatest],[LastModified],[MarkedForDelete],[VersionID]) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(deleteitems['Key'],deleteitems['IsLatest'],deleteitems['LastModified'],MarkedforDelete, deleteitems['VersionId']))
conn_db.commit()
```

> pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, "Incorrect syntax near
>   'qb_QWQDrabGr7FTBREfhCLMZLw4ztx'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity
>   15: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server")

Is there a way to make Python, pymssql\mysql force insert the string? Is there a string manipulation technique that I am not using? I have tried pypyodbc but no luck.

Edit: My current patch is to alter the string and add a flag to the row so I remember that the string starts with `0x`

Comment: What is the error message you receive?

Comment: Without more information, I would guess its incorrectly converting the string to binary / hex because of the '0x' at the beginning of the string.

Comment: That was my assumption too but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to rewrite what I have so far.

Comment: What is the datatype for that column? And you really need to parameterize your queries instead of building up strings and executing them.

Comment: It is a varchar(200) and I am guessing that parameterize is using `?` instead of `%s` ?

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for that hint, I gave the solution posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I came up with.

Since running the insert command with the appropriate values worked, I created a stored procedure in SQL to handle my request

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_S3Files]
@Key_ varchar(4000),
@IsLatest_ varchar(200),
@Size_ varchar(200),
@LastModified_ varchar(200),
@MarkedForDelete_ varchar(200),
@VersionID_ varchar(200)
AS
insert into [TestDB].[dbo].[S3_Files] ([Key],[IsLatest],[Size(Bytes)],[LastModified],[MarkedForDelete],[VersionID]) values (@Key_, @IsLatest_, @Size_, @LastModified_, @MarkedForDelete_, @VersionID_)
```

Then I call it through Python

```
modkey = deleteitems['Key'].replace("'", "''")
cursor.execute("""exec TestDB.dbo.stp_S3Files
    @Key_               = '%s'
    ,@IsLatest_          =  %s
    ,@Size_              = '%s'
    ,@LastModified_      = '%s' 
    ,@MarkedForDelete_   = '%s'
    ,@VersionID_         = '%s' """ %(modkey, deleteitems['IsLatest'],deleteitems['Size'],deleteitems['LastModified'],MarkedforDelete,deleteitems['VersionId']))
conn_db.commit()
```

Note: the string replace is to handle path names with ' to escape the character. I hope this helps someone who has the same issue down the road.